# Regex - negative lookahead & respond based on match length

Tags: javascript, regex

I read a bit in [this](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind) article, but I am not sure why I am failing:

`Output.replaceAll("(?<=\s)(?!<).*(?=@)", "xxxx")`

As an example, this will be the sample text:

```
To: <username@gmail.com>
I sent an e-mail to username@gmail.com yesterday
```

Here, what I want to achieve is replace `username` in  `username@gmail.com` to "xxxx".

I already have a regex for replacing `username` in `<username@gmail.com>`, which works like a charm:

`Output.replaceAll("(?<=<).*(?=@)", "xxxx")`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

By the way, I am replacing with hardcoded "xxxx" because I do not understand how to replace with certain amounts of "x" based on the length of the matched result. For example, "username" is 8 characters, so I want to replace it with "x" 8 times ("xxxxxxxx"). Any idea what I should be looking at to learn that? I googled a few times but never found any articles, so I guess I just do not know the right terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match any non space character followed by any combination of non-space characters and the `@` symbol.

```
[^\s<](?=\S*@)
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/jY69EI/1).

Comment: Thanks again! I understand the x part now. This is amazing! I played around with it and noticed that it would wrongly replace "To" if I put that line at the beginning of the text: https://regex101.com/r/HMt2s6/2 Why is that?

Comment: You're right, that's because `\G` matches start of string too. In order to negate it, it's necessary to add a condition for the second matching group. I'll just update the answer. @hofebido

Comment: Nice! That works amazingly well. I understand the concept a lot better now, thanks to you. Appreciate that you spent your time guiding me! <3

Comment: Hey @hofebido, I may have found an even better solution for this while reasoning by myself. Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/4W3o4M/1

Comment: thank you @lemon, what a nice and short one

Answer (score 2):

Note that `\G` is not supported by Javascript.

You can match 1+ chars other than not allowed characters and then match the `@` and then in the replacement repeat the x char and subtract 1 from the length.

```
[^\s@<>]+@
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LXJk5q/1).

```js
    const regex = /[^\s@<>]+@/g;
    const str = `To: <@gmail.com>
I sent an e-mail to a@gmail.com yesterday

To: <aa@gmail.com>
I sent an e-mail to aaa@gmail.com yesterday`;
    console.log(str.replace(regex, m => `${'x'.repeat(m.length - 1)}@`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `.*` in your regex with `[^\s]+`.

As for replacing with xxx, `replaceAll` function can accept a function as a replacer:

```js
console.log(
    "I sent an e-mail to username@gmail.com yesterday".replaceAll(
    /(?<=\s)(?!<)[^\s]+(?=@)/g, 
    (...match) => {
        let username = match[0]
        let replacer = ""
        for (let i = 0; i < username.length; i++){
            replacer += "x"
        }
        return replacer
    })
)
```

You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Just saw this as well, really helpful, thanks a lot Nikita! :)